# simple nltk sentiment analysis code using python3

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to do some classification on customer emails.

1. Is the email happy or sad (sentiment analysis)
2. Is the email related to billing or not.

I am using Python3 and think I have to use nltk and scikit
NLTK - will help understand and read the text I beleive
scikit - will do the classification (happy, sad and billing or not)

Training data set 1: A few phrases...anywhere from one word to a sentence with 5 to 6 words.
(1 being happy and 0 being not happy)...a few examples below

- Apprecaite the  help..1
- great job..1
- Awesome..1
- terrible..0
- confusing...0
- slow down...0

Training data set 2: a few phrases indicating billing related question..(few examples  below)

- question on my bill
- billing fee
- my bill is too high
- payment rejected

Now this seems to be straight forward from a concept stand point
where can I find some basic code, that will tell me

1. how I can use my own training data
2. how I can load the email text as input and spit out an answer happy or sad...and billing or not.

Comment: Useful: https://github.com/hb20007/hands-on-nltk-tutorial/blob/master/5-2-Sentiment-Analysis-with-nltk.sentiment.SentimentAnalyzer-and-VADER-tools.ipynb

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your data sets, your approach is nearly lexicon-based as the items contains very few words.

For billing, the lexicon-based approach should be a good idea. You should give importance to the subjects of the emails.

For sentiment analysis you have two options:

- **Machine learning:** In this case you should use a bigger data set (in my view, each item should be a full email). You can implement a Naive Bayes classifier following [this tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html).
- **Lexicon-based approach:** There are several lexicons for sentiment analysis e.g. [SentiWordNet](http://sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it/) (downloadable from `nltk.download()`), [MPQA](http://mpqa.cs.pitt.edu/), [SentiStrength](http://sentistrength.wlv.ac.uk/), [WordNet-Affect via WNAffect](https://github.com/clemtoy/WNAffect),... Preprocessings: tokenization (`nltk.word_tokenize()`) and POS tagging (`nltk.pos_tag(text)`). You should also think about negation (polarity shifting is a good approach to manage with negation).

Machine Learning provide best results so if you have enough annotated emails it is the good choice.

Comment: thx Clemtoy..! further question to followup on the lexicon based approach.(billing) .I'm going to be using NLTK to derive meaning full data from my text(remove stop words..etc)...then do I simply compare words to my own training data ? (billing phrases ?)  #1. compare single words with single words in my training data....#2 compare bi grams with 2 word phrases from my data...#3 compare n (3 word) grams with n (4 words) in my training data...and then 4 words till I am thinkin maybe 7 word phrases is the max I have for now..ex. "I have a question on my bill".. so guess I look and compare ngrams?

Comment: You can try to do this yes!

Comment: btw...other than emails...which is going to be a small portion of my data...majority is going to be phone calls transcribed to text...will keep my fingers crossed !